# React native should use the following kind of SDK

Tags: reactjs, react-native, sdk

The printer provides the following SDKs, but I don't know whether React Native uses js SDK or Android SDK or other, or it is not available. Can you give me some suggestions, thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Android SDK.

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
const { CalendarModule } = NativeModules;
CalendarModule.createCalendarEvent('testName', 'testLocation');
```

https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android